# Store several images as ndarrays into one 4 dimensional ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop, where I read images and resize them to `32x32x3`

```
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):            
    img = plt.imread(path+filename)
    out = imresize(img, [32,32])
```

I tried to store it in a list and convert it to an numpy array

```
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):    
    img = plt.imread(path+filename)
    out = imresize(img, [32,32])
    inet_signs.append(out)
a = np.array(inet_signs)
```

But this only resulted in the error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,32,3) into
>   shape (32,32)

Comment: `imresize(img, [32,32,3])` works?

Comment: No, that won't work.

Comment: I think the code you have would work, the array conversion I mean: `np.array([np.random.rand(32,32) for _ in range(3)])`. I think one or more of your images is RGB rather than grayscale, so the resulting list has elements of different shape; hence the error about broadcasting. Check `img.shape)` before doing anything with it, for each file. Are they the same?

Comment: If you fix this problem, you'll have to use `np.dstack` instead of `np.array` to get an output of shape `(32,32,3)` instead of `(3,32,32)`.

Comment: Obviously, this won't work. If the images are `RGB`, then you either have to convert to `grayscale` explicitly or average all the channels before resizing the images. Then, it's just concatenating all the nD arrays depthwise